# Why can I not use Continuation when using a proxy class to access MS CRM 2013?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

So I have a standard service reference proxy calss for MS CRM 2013 (i.e. right-click add reference etc...) I then found the limitation that CRM data calls limit to 50 results and I wanted to get the full list of results.  I found two methods, one looks more correct, but doesn't seem to work.  I was wondering why it didn't and/or if there was something I'm doing incorrectly.

*Basic setup and process*

```cs
crmService = new CrmServiceReference.MyContext(new Uri(crmWebServicesUrl));
crmService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
var accountAnnotations = crmService.AccountSet.Where(a => a.AccountNumber = accountNumber).Select(a => a.Account_Annotation).FirstOrDefault();
```

*Using Continuation (something I want to work, but looks like it doesn't)*

```cs
while (accountAnnotations.Continuation != null)
{
   accountAnnotations.Load(crmService.Execute<Annotation>(accountAnnotations.Continuation.NextLinkUri));
}
```

using that method .Continuation is always null and accountAnnotations.Count is always 50 (but there are more than 50 records)

---

*After struggling with .Continutation for a while I've come up with the following alternative method (but it seems "not good")*

```cs
var accountAnnotationData = accountAnnotations.ToList();
var accountAnnotationFinal = accountAnnotations.ToList();
var index = 1;

while (accountAnnotationData.Count == 50)
{
   accountAnnotationData = (from a in crmService.AnnotationSet
                           where a.ObjectId.Id == accountAnnotationData.First().ObjectId.Id
                           select a).Skip(50 * index).ToList();
   accountAnnotationFinal = accountAnnotationFinal.Union(accountAnnotationData).ToList();
   index++;
}
```

So the second method seems to work, but for any number of reasons it doesn't seem like the best.  Is there a reason .Continuation is always null?  Is there some setup step I'm missing or some nice way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The way to get the records from CRM is to use paging here is an example with a query expression but you can also use fetchXML if you want

```
//  Query using the paging cookie.
// Define the paging attributes.
// The number of records per page to retrieve.
int fetchCount = 3;
// Initialize the page number.
int pageNumber = 1;
// Initialize the number of records.
int recordCount = 0;
// Define the condition expression for retrieving records.
ConditionExpression pagecondition = new ConditionExpression();

pagecondition.AttributeName = "address1_stateorprovince";

pagecondition.Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal;
pagecondition.Values.Add("WA");

// Define the order expression to retrieve the records.
OrderExpression order = new OrderExpression();
order.AttributeName = "name";
order.OrderType = OrderType.Ascending;

// Create the query expression and add condition.
QueryExpression pagequery = new QueryExpression();
pagequery.EntityName = "account";
pagequery.Criteria.AddCondition(pagecondition);
pagequery.Orders.Add(order);
pagequery.ColumnSet.AddColumns("name", "address1_stateorprovince", "emailaddress1", "accountid");

// Assign the pageinfo properties to the query expression.
pagequery.PageInfo = new PagingInfo();
pagequery.PageInfo.Count = fetchCount;
pagequery.PageInfo.PageNumber = pageNumber;

// The current paging cookie. When retrieving the first page, 
// pagingCookie should be null.
pagequery.PageInfo.PagingCookie = null;
Console.WriteLine("#\tAccount Name\t\t\tEmail Address");while (true)
{
    // Retrieve the page.
    EntityCollection results = _serviceProxy.RetrieveMultiple(pagequery);
    if (results.Entities != null)
    {
        // Retrieve all records from the result set.
        foreach (Account acct in results.Entities)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}.\t{1}\t\t{2}",
                               ++recordCount,
                               acct.EMailAddress1,
                              acct.Name);
        }
    }
    // Check for more records, if it returns true.
    if (results.MoreRecords)
    {
        // Increment the page number to retrieve the next page.
        pagequery.PageInfo.PageNumber++;
        // Set the paging cookie to the paging cookie returned from current results.
        pagequery.PageInfo.PagingCookie = results.PagingCookie;
    }
    else
    {
        // If no more records are in the result nodes, exit the loop.
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, what I'm looking for is the proper way to do it using the CrmServiceReference proxy class that Visual Studio creates when creating a service reference.

Comment: Ohhh I see well then I have found the following : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg985388.aspx look there. The example it is for crm 2011 and silverlight but the principle is still the same. scroll down the page for the sample code

Comment: yes, I have seen that, but was trying to do something similar to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee474410%28v=vs.100%29.aspx but using the proxy class generated by visual studio and was wondering why my .continuation is always null (rather than having the link to the next 50 items)